# Ada How to get input a list of integer from a user and put it into an array

Tags: arrays, input, ada

Im sorry to ask this question but Ada is really strict on an input and output system so I cant figure out how to get the input from a the user and put it into an array.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada;

procedure Main is
 type MY_ARRAY is array(1..9) of INTEGER;
   Data        : MY_ARRAY;

begin
   Put("Please input the series of numbers");
   Get_Line(Data);
end Main;
```

I know this is completely wrong but I research everywhere and I cant find how people get the input to an array LOL. Thank yall for help.

Comment: Also consider [*Command line arguments for Ada*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14491899/230513).

Comment: That link look like it is dealing with the character string tho. Is Ada has any kind of getting the array input ? Thanks for help man.

Comment: Might the task be to put single numbers into the components of an array? Or, to that effect, to find a way of extracting single numbers from a string?

Comment: Have you read section A.10 in the language reference manual?  It describes how `Ada.Text_IO` (and `Ada.Integer_Text_IO`) works in great detail?

Comment: You might want to consider using a loop to read values and place them in your array.

Comment: To be explicit, the Ada standard library does not provide any way of reading from standard input or a file to fill an array of any kind of object (other than `Character`, of course, in the form of `String`s). You have to code the loop and (at its simplest, without e.g. any error checking) use `Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get` for each element of `Data` in succession.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to use only the package Ada.Text_IO so that you can read each number as a String and then store it as an integer one by one using a for loop and `Integer'Value`, which converts from String to Integer.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    type MY_ARRAY is array(1..9) of Integer;
    Data : MY_ARRAY;

begin
    Put_Line("Please input the series of numbers");

    for I in 1..MY_ARRAY'Length loop
        Data(I) := Integer'Value(Get_Line);
    end loop;
end Main;
```